# getting url of window opened with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to find out the href of a youtube video associated with a button. This button is located in a page I don't own. My application uses a Rails backend.

The html element:

```
<a href="#" class="lnk" title="whatever">
    <span class="ifram-you"></span>
    <span class="tub-container"></span>
    <span class="tube-i"></span>
</a>
```

After clicking the button, a new window opens and jquery dynamically assigns a youtube video by using the youtube api. So far I have tried:
1. using the gem mechanize to see the window jquery opens, but mechanize isnt able to follow javascript.
2. assigning the button.click() to a var in the console. Doesnt work either, as click returns undefined

I know the referrer of the new window is where I clicked the button. Is there any way of knowing if my window opened a pop-up or if my window is some other window's referer?

Otherwise, is my problem solvable with any other approach?

Comment: It's not button, it's a link. did you try: `$('a.lnk').on('click', console.log(this));`?

Comment: @Surya yes, it is a link but it has a fake anchor with a jquery onclick listener. Thus, there is no way of knowing the href before clicking as jquery will assign it later after a query. I also tried adding event listeners to onclick but the problem with that is that the video is not yet loaded and "this" will point to the current window.(I checked by doing $('a.youtube_link').on('click', nwin = this); and then looking at the var nwin)

I realized that the video is loaded in the Developer Tools: Sources, can I access that?

Comment: @Person who edited my post. You changed referer to referrer, so you might find this informative http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer